# Python looping when there is only one item in the list

Tags: loops, python-3.6

Hello i need to loop over a few accounts but sometimes there is only one account. What is the best way to do that please?

Here is what i tried but this fails when there is only one account in the list.

```
accounts = ('X123456','Y325252')
for account in accounts:
    do stuff
```

Sorry about the beginners question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use parenthesis to initialize a tuple, add a comma in there like so: `a = ("bc",)`.

If there is only one item without a comma, Python returns only the single item, and then the `for`-loop iterates through each character.
I.E `a = ("b", "c")` returns `('b','c')` and `a = ("bc")` returns `bc`.

```
a = ("b", "c");
print(a);     # ('b', 'c')
a = ("bc");
print(a);     # bc
```

Instead, you could use either braces or brackets, or add a comma as shown above.
These are always treated as a tuple (or list).

```
accounts = ['X123456','Y325252']
for account in accounts:
    do stuff
```

Comment: No problem, it happens :)

Comment: @steff if the answer is hit your question, you should accept it!

Comment: You can have one-element tuples.

Comment: @MarkTolonen not with parenthesis. `a = ("bc"); print(type(a));` returns str. `a = ("b", "c"); print(type(a));` returns tuple

Comment: `a = 1,` and `a = (1,)` are both one-element tuples.  The comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses.  The parentheses aren't even needed except in cases of clarification, like calling a function such as `f(1,(2,))` which passes an int and a one-element tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a one-element list or tuple. Any of the following will work:

```
accounts = 'X123456', # one-element tuple 
accounts = ('X123456',) # also tuple
accounts = ['X123456'] # list
```

Note the comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses, which is why you can leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

A Python for loop will iterate over each item in a tuple or each character in a string. A string in parentheses is just a string. Python doesn't realize it's a tuple unless there is a comma within the parentheses.

**Example:**

```
In : tuple1 = ('this', 'that') 
In : tuple2 = ('this')
In : tuple3 = ('this',)

In : tuple1[0]
Out: 'this'

In : tuple2[0]
Out: 't'

In : tuple3[0]
Out: 'this'


In : for item in tuple2:
...:     print(item)
...: 
t
h
i
s

In : for item in tuple3:
...:     print(item)
...: 
this
```

Comment: Your latest version is a lot more accurate. One correctin, though: "A tuple with one item is interpreted as a string unless it has a trailing comma." A tuple with one item is a tuple with one item. You just have to be careful of the syntax to get the thing you want. In your example, `tuple2` is not in fact a tuple. **It is a string.** This is because `(x)` is parsed as parentheses around a single value similar to how `(x + y)` groups the operation. On the other hand `(x,)` is a tuple with a single item.